# Cортировка товаров в Woocommerce: чтобы товары без цены или с ценой 0 показывались в конце списка?

Tags: woocommerce

Сейчас стоит сортировка по умолчанию по цене возрастание, но в каталоге много товаров без цены или с ценой 0.

Как сделать так чтобы эти товары показывались не в начале списка товаров а в конце не меняя способ сортировки.

Пробовал вот этот код. Но не работает.

```
// Товары без цены или с ценой равной нулю будут в конце списка
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_stock_status', 50, 2);
function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!is_admin() && is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy())) {
        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = "price_query.price > 0 DESC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
    }
    return $posts_clauses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.
Может кому-то пригодится.

```
// Товары без цены или с ценой равной нулю будут в конце списка
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_no_price', 50, 2);
function order_by_no_price($posts_clauses) {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!is_admin() && is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product_taxonomy())) {
        if($posts_clauses['join']!=' LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON wp_posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id '){
            $posts_clauses['join'] = $posts_clauses['join'] . " LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup ON wp_posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id ";    
        }        
        $posts_clauses['orderby'] = "wc_product_meta_lookup.min_price > 0 DESC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
    }   
    return $posts_clauses;
}
```

Comment: Неработают ваши решения, зачем вы их по всему интернету разбрасываете